# Is there Flink sink connector to ksqldb tables?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, ksqldb, flink-sql

I have working Flink app and all output shouts to stdout. I want to upsert results to **ksqldb** table. Is there any Flink connector for that?

Answer (score 0):

There's always a backing topic for each ksqldb table ([the KAFKA_TOPIC parameter](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/create-table/)).

You can insert data in this topic with the [Flink Kafka connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/)

Comment: There's also an Upsert Kafka connector for Flink SQL (which you can use from the DataStream API if that's what you need). https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/upsert-kafka/